# Bus error when calling Pause in OSX

Tags: macos, assembly

```
section .text 
  global start

start:
  mov eax, 29
  int 80h
  ret
```

I'm pretty sure that `pause(void)` is syscall 29, so why is this giving me `Bus error: 10`?

Answer (score 2):

According to [`sys/syscall.h`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1228.5.20/bsd/sys/syscall.h):

```
#define SYS_recvfrom       29
```

I would guess that `recvfrom` takes some other parameter, giving you the buss error.

---

If you are actually trying to call `pause(void)`, a cursory examination of source seems to suggest that the definitions are something like the following:

`syscalls.h`:

```
#define SYS_sigsuspend     111
```

[`sigsuspend.c`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-167/sys.subproj/sigsuspend.c):

```
int
sigsuspend (
            const sigset_t *sigmask_p
)
{
    sigset_t    mask;

    if (sigmask_p)
        mask = *sigmask_p;
    else
        sigemptyset(&mask);
    return syscall (SYS_sigsuspend, mask);
}
```

[`sigcompat.c`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-167/compat43.subproj/sigcompat.c):

```
int sigpause(mask)
    int mask;
{
    return (sigsuspend((sigset_t *)&mask));
}
```

[`sigpause.c`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-167/gen.subproj/pause.c):

```
int
pause()
{
    return sigpause(sigblock(0L));
}
```

So, while the `pause(void)` may not take any parameters, the syscall certainly does.

---

To call `pause(void)` from assembly, link with `libc`:

example.asm:

```
section .text 
  global start

start:
  call pause
  ret
```

Compile with `as -o example.o example.asm` and link with `gcc -static -o a.out example.o`

Comment: All the documentation (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_system_calls/pause.htm) I've seen though says that Pause doesn't take any additional parameters??

Comment: @sircodesalot, pause is not a syscall in the sense that you can trigger it with an interrupt.  It is a system call in the sense that it is in libc.  Further, the system call you are listing is not in any way related to `pause` for the versions of OS X I could find.

Comment: `pause is not a syscall in the sense that you can trigger it with an interrupt`. How would you trigger a system call without an interrupt? Also, the `pause` call is listed here (http://asm.sourceforge.net/syscall.html), with the preface: "these are not libc 'system calls', but real system calls provided by Linux Kernel." Could it be that OSX doesn't actually support this call? (but then why would it work in C?)

Comment: @sircodesalot, system calls are specific to the kernel you are calling.  You linked to a page specific to Linux.  As I posted, the libc implementation of pause does generate several system calls (`SYS_sigsuspend` and `SYS_syssetprocmask` to be specific).  You would be better off linking to libc and calling the true `pause` method, rather than trying to make system calls directly.

Comment: `You would be better off linking to libc and calling the true pause method.` In the interim, thats not a bad idea, thanks.